# How do I hide a file or folder by deactivating all show and hide checkboxs in window 7 & 8

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, windows-explorer, windows-registry

I'm trying to hiding one file or folder by deactivate all `show` and `hide` checkboxs in Windows 7 & 8.

I know about changing the value of `checkedvalue` data to `0` in the following registry address to deactivate show functionality in the Image1.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\ SOFTWARE\ Microsoft\ Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\Folder\Hidden\SHOWALL
```

Image1:

[image]

... and every things work well. It can force hide the hidden files and folders **But** I see an checkbox item in Windows 8 explorer ribbon bar named `Hidden Items` (image 2). If I check it my files & folders will be shown.

Image2:

[image]

- How can I deactivate this checkbox functionality from registry too?
- Is there a way to deactivate `Hide protected operation system file` checkbox functionality in registry too?

I want a safe and complete way to force hide some of my files in windows 7 & 8. It will be a good way for me if the solution be based on registry manipulation.

I don't need any third party software and tools to encrypt or whatever, I just want a way based on change the windows registry.

Comment: Note that whatever registry manipulation you use to achieve your goal can always be undone by an Administrator ... if you really want to prevent access to your files then hiding them is not a good solution you should be looking at encryption.

Comment: @DavidPostill, my problem is special. The encryption is a appropriate way but i need my files as normal format (as decrypt) because they should be used by another program. I want put them inside a folder (by a c# program) as some hidden files then lock the unhide feature of windows for some moments, then remove the files programmatically and reverse the windows show hidden files to normal mode. Unfortunately, there is not another way in my project, so i need a registry trick (a reliable solution) to deactivate this features of windows just for some moments.

Comment: If you can explain **why** you have this **special requirement** someone might be able to offer an alternative solution ...