# Redirect opening requests about a file in a given directory to another file in another directory

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-explorer, hardlink

I have a simple scenario, but i don't now is there a way in `Windows` to do it or not:

We have 2 directory with these files:

**Book:**

```
   D:\sources\Books
                |___ A.pdf
                |___ B.pdf
```

**Lib:**

```
   E:\extra\text\science\Lib
                          |___ X.pdf
                          |___ Y.pdf
```

---

Notic: the **X.pdf** is inside the **Lib** folder

---

Now, i want:

1. **Redirect** each opening request about `D:\sources\Books\X.pdf` to `E:\extra\text\science\Lib\X.pdf`
2. The solution **should not** lead to `X.pdf` shown in `Book` folder when the users open `Book` folder by `windows explorer` (it should be opened by `typing the path in windows explorer address bar` or `CMD` or commands of a software)

---

Question Notes:

1. Your solution works in witch windows versions?
2. Is there a way for Windows `XP`, `7` and `8`?
3. Is `NTFS` requied in your solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will create a symbolic link in D:~\Books that leads to E:~\Lib and then set the hidden attribute (+H), the /L switch ensures the attribute is set only on the symlink.  The link will be visible in Windows only if the user has set the visibility of hidden files manually:

`MKLINK D:\sources\Books\X.pdf E:\extra\text\science\lib\X.pdf | ATTRIB +H D:\sources\Books\X.pdf /L`

Sources: Windows command line help for  `MKLINK` and `ATTRIB`.

Symbolic Links only work with NTFS in Windows.  If either or both file systems are in FAT32, you would have to use a shortcut.  Shortcuts cannot be easily created from the command line, so just `right click`-> "New" -> "Shortcut" -> type in `E:\extra\text\science\lib\X.pdf` -> "Next" -> type in `X.pdf` -> "Finish" -> `right click on the shortcut' -> "Properties" -> "General" tab -> check "Hidden".  This also will not be visible unless the user has manually selected the visibility of hidden files.

The major difference is that the symlink is created at the file system level and will normally be treated as the file itself whereas the shortcut is a separate file that runs a script and will actually have the full name of `X.pdf.lnk'.  For your purposes that shouldn't matter unless you are trying to manipulate the file with scripts.

N.B. neither the symlink nor the shortcut will be visible from the terminal either, unless the user types `DIR /A` to show hidden files; however, they will work.  If necessary, you can disable the ability of users to view hidden files from Windows Explorer using the (GUI) regedit.exe or from the command line with `REG`.  Review the `REG /?` and take a look at this article: http://www.askvg.com/the-best-method-to-hide-files-folders-in-windows-without-using-3rd-party-utilities/ and the accompanying article: http://www.askvg.com/all-kinds-of-restrictions-for-windows-2000-xp-2003-and-vista/, in particular item 4.  A problem with this of course is that the user may have a legitimate need to see a hidden file someday.

Comment: Thanks @Doug, your answer is useful so i marked it as answer. also i want prevent user in any way to view link and target file. I'm a C# programmer & can change the users registry with my software. i has written a question about it before. have you any idea about it? : [My Question](http://superuser.com/questions/846305/how-do-i-hide-a-file-or-folder-by-deactivating-all-show-and-hide-checkboxs-in-wi)

Comment: @RAM, I've edited to add a little information about the `REG`.  I hope this is useful.  I'm afraid I know nothing about C#.